# Generar consulta que agrupe materias por alumno

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

Solicito de su apoyo amigos para resolver una consulta que he intentado generar:  Tengo una relación de alumnos - materias, algunas materias se repiten en la relación con misma clave, horario solo es diferenciado por salón y docente que imparte.  Mi objetivo es obtener el numero de alumnos por materia, pero tengo el inconveniente del anterior párrafo, son 4 materias por alumno para este ejemplo a citar:

```sql
SELECT
cve_mat
,count(cve_mat) as proyeccion
FROM [Escolares].[dbo].[irregulares_p]
where cve_mat = '00949'
group by cve_mat
```

Resultado:

Materia: 00949

Proyeccion: 24

```sql
SELECT

cve_unica
,count(distinct cve_mat) as proyeccion
FROM [Escolares].[dbo].[irregulares_p]
where cve_mat = '00949'
```

Resultado cve_unica proyeccion
0257094 1
0281940 1
0292581 1
0295377 1
0299690 1
0299703 1

Lo que espero conseguir es:

Materia: 00949

Proyeccion: 6 (alumnos que tiene la relación con la materia buscada)  Muchas gracias por su atención y ayuda, un saludo.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta esto:

```sql
SELECT cve_mat, sum(cve_mat) as proyeccion
FROM [Escolares].[dbo].[irregulares_p]
where cve_mat = '00949'
```

Y si no es así (porque no haz colocado nombres de tus tablas ni nada detallado), la idea no debería cambiar mucho; intenta esto:

```sql
SELECT cve_mat as materia, sum(proyeccion) as proyeccion
FROM [Escolares].[dbo].[irregulares_p]
where cve_mat = '00949'
```

> Donde proyección representa a la columna donde almacenan los alumnos.

---

**EDIT:**

```sql
SELECT cve_mat AS Materia, COUNT(DISTINCT columnaAlumnos) AS Proyeccion
FROM [Escolares].[dbo].[irregulares_p]
GROUP BY cve_mat
```

Comment: Saludos, gracias amigo, te comento la consulta es a una misma tabla en donde esta la relación de materias por alumno, contiene unos 20 campos, los principales son cve_unica, cve_mat los demás campos se refieren a detalle de salón, días, docente, entre otros...

Entre la relación están materias que se repiten 4 ó 5 veces por alumno, misma clave, horario pero con diferente maestro, lo que intento es obtener el numero de alumnos que cursaran cada materia de la relación de datos. Ej.

Taller 1 - 6 alumnos (taller 1 aparece 4 veces por alumno 6 alumnos en total )

Gracias.

Comment: Lo edité por si aún te sirve.

Answer (score 0):

Amigos, he solucionado la consulta de la siguiente forma:

SELECT
cve_mat
,count(distinct cve_unica) as proyeccion
FROM [Escolares].[dbo].[irregulares_p]
group by cve_mat

Y así sencillo obtuve el resultado esperado.

Gracias por el tiempo.